# Random characters being changed in Access fields

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a db containing info for a party.
I have a look-up field for who invited them, this is just a list of 4 names.
When I change this it **changes characters** in the `last name` column of the **same row** to ones that weren't even in the normal Latin alphabet.
The **reverse** happened as when I went to change it back it then **changed the** `invited by` column into some Chinese (looking) characters, breaking it's own validation as I said only items in the list were allowed, but it was fine with that for some reason.

Any idea what could be going on in this situation?

Also when I create a new table it doesn't appear in the Access Objects list until I reopen the database

Comment: Have you tried doing a "Compact and Repair Database" operation? (It's under the "DATABASE TOOLS" tab of the Access 2013 ribbon bar.)

Comment: That appears to have fixed it thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been caused by some corruption in the Access database file. Performing a "Compact and Repair Database" operation in Access appears to have resolved it.